# Displaying username in profile section of a Web Application

Tags: web-application, web-browser, websites

Is it a good idea to display the username in the user profile section of a web application, when the user is already logged in?
My web application uses basic authentication and does not have any 2 factor authentication. What could be the impact?

Answer (score 1):

I would say displaying the username on the page (often in the top navbar) is not a matter of security but user experience. Maybe it's possible to have multiple accounts in the application, then it's nice to see which of your accounts is currently logged in. Or maybe you have a "normal" account and an "administrative" account or such things.

In terms of security, this only may prevent you from "accidently" sign in with a different account. But that does not happen quite often ;-) Instead, a typical scneraio would be a hacker stealing your credentials or access token and uses the site with your account - but you don't stop him doing this by displaying or not displaying the username in the navbar or somewhere else.

Comment: what if the hacker steals user's session cookie and then can see the username in nav bar and all they have to do is guess the password and then they have re-entry. Is this far fetched?

Comment: If a hacker has successfully obtained a valid access token you have bigger problems then this. With a valid access token he doesn't need the password anymore because he already HAS access to the website. The password only would be interesting if he wants to use the website for a longer time then the token is valid. But aside from that - somehwhere in your app you should display the username. For example, you may want to give your users the chance to change the username. Another point, you should limit the login-attempts for a user! There must not be a way to "try" passwords.